# Why Celery worker gives "OSError: Socket closed"

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery, worker, broker

My celery worker that works with rabbitMQ keeps giving me a socket error -- see below -- after working for a few minutes. I'd like to know what could be the main cause of the problem? I thought that it could be the firewall. But, disabling the firewall did not solve the problem.
I am working on a Windows 10 machine.

```
C:\Users\user_\Desktop\Aida>celery -A tasks worker -l info -P eventlet

 -------------- celery@user-RazerBlade v4.2.0 (windowlicker)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0 2018-07-13 12:27:03
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x4b95370
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (eventlet)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> queueA           exchange=(direct) key=tasks.task_1
                .> queueB           exchange=(direct) key=tasks.task_2
                .> queueC           exchange=(direct) key=tasks.task_3
                .> queueD           exchange=(direct) key=tasks.task_4

[tasks]
  . tasks.task_1
  . tasks.task_2
  . tasks.task_3
  . tasks.task_4

[2018-07-13 12:27:03,119: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2018-07-13 12:27:03,133: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-07-13 12:27:04,166: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-07-13 12:27:04,212: INFO/MainProcess] pidbox: Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//.
[2018-07-13 12:27:04,217: INFO/MainProcess] celery@user-RazerBlade ready.
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,270: WARNING/MainProcess] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,271: WARNING/MainProcess] File "c:\users\user_\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs\selects.py", line 55, in wait
    listeners.get(fileno, noop).cb(fileno)
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,276: WARNING/MainProcess] File "c:\users\user_\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\pidbox.py", line 120, in loop
    connection.drain_events(timeout=1.0)
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,277: WARNING/MainProcess] File "c:\users\user_\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 301, in drain_events
    return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,278: WARNING/MainProcess] File "c:\users\user_\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 103, in drain_events
    return connection.drain_events(**kwargs)
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,279: WARNING/MainProcess] File "c:\users\user_\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 491, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,281: WARNING/MainProcess] File "c:\users\user_\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 496, in blocking_read
    frame = self.transport.read_frame()
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,285: WARNING/MainProcess] File "c:\users\user_\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 243, in read_frame
    frame_header = read(7, True)
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,286: WARNING/MainProcess] File "c:\users\user_\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 426, in _read
    raise IOError('Socket closed')
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,287: WARNING/MainProcess] OSError: Socket closed
[2018-07-13 12:30:04,288: WARNING/MainProcess] Removing descriptor: 756
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not windows user but I'll try to give you some hints.

(1) - check if your rabbitmq configuration matches your connection string (specifically in linux I can configure rabbitmq to only listen on specific interface so it would not accept connections on, say, loop back interface); The configuration option I would check is `NODE_IP_ADDRESS`

(2) - assuming you are 100% certain your rabbitmq is running I'd check if `NODENAME` is matching your factual system configuration (i.e. check for host name correctness)

(3) - the most obvious but still worth checking is if your rabbitmq user is correct (I see you have `guest` user, did you create this user yourself? did you give it permissions to your specific vhost?)

(4) - and this leads to another obvious question if your connection string is correct. My connection string looks something like this `BROKER_URL = 'amqp://my_user:very_secret_password@localhost:5672/my_vhost_name` (and on this one from your log it seems you have not configured your connection string to use vhost)

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error while running celery workers using --without-heartbeat option.
Removing the --without-heartbeat option made this go away.

I think to correctly make --without-heartbeat work, we need to make changes to the broker's heartbeat settings to stop it from disconnecting consumers who don't send heartbeats. Haven't tried this though.